# Image editing with universal windows app in C#

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, image-processing, win-universal-app

I am trying to build a Universal Windows App in C# that involves opening an image, re-sizing it, editing some of the pixels' RGB values and saving it again. After looking around the net for a while I found that most people seemed to be using the namespace "System.Drawing.Imaging" to do similar things, however when I tried to include "System.Drawing.Imaging", Visual Studio told me that the namespace didn't exist.

I believed this may just be that some namespaces that are available for .NET programs are not available for Universal Windows Apps, so I tried looking around some more and found a similar namespace that could be used, "Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging", however this one is much more limited than "System.Drawing.Imaging" and cannot read or edit pixels as far as I could tell.

Is there another namespace I could use, or a way to get "System.Drawing.Imaging" to in a Universal Windows App? If there isn't anyway of doing something like this with a Universal Windows App in C#, is there a way to do it in another language? Any tips or pointers would help.

Answer (score 2):

For straight pixel manipulations you can use Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging[WriteableBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) and stream out of and back into its [PixelBuffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) property. There is a third party library [WriteableBitmapEx](https://github.com/teichgraf/WriteableBitmapEx/) which provides extension methods to perform higher level manipulations on the buffer.

Another alternate is the [Win2D](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D) library which exposes the low level Direct2D and DirectWrite libraries to UWP apps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try both of these out.